# ADB Debug over remote desktop

Tags: android, android-studio, rdp

Essentially I have 2 computers. One a client, on a network that I can't edit, and a 'server' that is running Android Studio, and whose network I can request adjustments made too. I would like to be able to compile an app from android studio to a device connected to the client. The client and server are not on the same network. Is there a way to do this? I've tried a few solutions but none of them work.

Edit: I'm not adverse to changing the remote software if need be

Answer (score 0):

If you can get both the computer with Android Studio and the device on the same wifi network you can use wireless adb.

Described here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless

Comment: Not really suitable for the use case. I need to be able to do it on different networks, thanks for the help anyway.